# Errors in building a BackboneJS Event Collection - new Event() throws errors

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

This seems pretty much as a standard use of a collection, but it doesnt work. I have the following code inside a document ready function:

```
$(function() {
  window.EventList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Event,
    url: '/events',
        parse: function(response) { // same result with or without parse function
      return _(response.rows).map(function(row) { return row.doc ;});
    }
  });         
  window.Events = new EventList;
  // throws Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
  // Events.fetch();
});
```

I've tested with Chromium and Firefox, FF is more verbose:

```
this.model is not a constructor at Backbone.js line:570
[Break On This Error] model = new this.model(attrs, {collection: this});
```

What am I missing?

As a sidenote, I'm trying to follow [Chris Storm's tutorial/chain](http://japhr.blogspot.com/2011/08/converting-to-backbonejs.html) if you need a bit more context.

Relevant Software Versions:

- jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.1
- Backbone.js 0.5.3
- Underscore.js 1.2.2
- Chromium 14.0.835.202 (Developer Build 103287 Linux) Ubuntu 11.10
- Firefox is 8.0, Ubuntu 11.10, 64 bits

**Update**: a little more debugging and I find that at the point the error is thrown, this.model has the value `function Event() { [native code] }` and calling `new Event()` throws more errors - `TypeError`. So what's wrong with creating events?

Comment: You should post the code for your Event model as it seems the error happens there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you (and Chris Storm) have simply chosen a bad name for your model. There is already an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event) in JavaScript (at least in a JavaScript that is [wired up to a DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event)); furthermore, you can't call `new Event()` to create a DOM Event object, you're supposed to use [`document.createEvent('Event')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Creating_and_triggering_events).

Try renaming your Event to, say, CalendarEvent:

```
$(function() {
  window.CalendarEvent     = Backbone.Model.extend({});
  window.CalendarEventList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: CalendarEvent,
    url: '/events',
    parse: function(response) {
      return _(response.rows).map(function(row) { return row.doc ;});
    }
  });         
  window.CalendarEvents = new CalendarEventList;
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much! I'll post a comment on his blog, in case anyone else stumbles over the same problem.